# API call being sent repeatedly on a React Native/Redux Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am working on a react native application, my stack consists of the following packages:

1. React Native
2. Styled Components
3. Redux and React-Redux and Thunk
4. Axios (for Making API calls)

I am trying to make an API call to headless cms and use the retrieved data. On Initial load API call will be made to load data from API.

**Problem:**

I've been at it for the last 3 days and can't figure out the issue, When I try to make an API call from a component using useEffect Hook, the API call is being sent multiple times, or that's what it looked like but I think API call is made repeatedly until one of them is rejected, or some error occurs. I have seen up to 10 API calls made repeatedly.

I have tried a few things, such as using the class component and putting the API call in the componentDidMount lifecycle method, but the result is the same. I have tried using local state and remove redux from component and that seems to work but then using redux defeats the purpose.

**My Code:**

**Reducer:**

the following reducer is responsible for handling the mentioned substate,

```js
import {FETCH_MEDITATION, FETCHING} from '../types';

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  data: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, {type, payload}) {
  switch (type) {
    case FETCHING: 
    return {
      isFetching: true,
      ...state,
    }
    case FETCH_MEDITATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: payload
      };
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Action Creator:**

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import {FETCH_MEDITATION} from '../types';
import getDeepProp from '../../utilities/getDeepProp';

export function fetchMeditation() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('fetching meditations');
    try {
      const fetch = await axios('http://xx8.1x9.xx.cv/meditations');
      const res = await fetch.data;

      const data = await res.map((item) => {
        return {
          id: getDeepProp(['id'], item),
          title: getDeepProp(['title'], item),
          tagline: getDeepProp(['tagline'], item),
          image: getDeepProp(
            ['featured_image', 'formats', 'thumbnail', 'url'],
            item,
          ),
          audio: getDeepProp(['audio', 'url'], item),
          total_time: getDeepProp(['total_time'], item),
          time_seconds: getDeepProp(['time_second'], item),
        };
      });

      console.log(data);

      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_MEDITATION,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}
```

**Connected Component Making API Call**

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Card from './Card';
import HorizontalGrid from './HorizontalGrid';
import {fetchMeditation} from '../../store/actions/meditation-actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const Meditation = (props) => {
  const handlePress = (soundData) => {
    Actions.player(soundData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchMeditation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <HorizontalGrid heading="Meditation">
      {props.meditation.map((item) => {
        const {id, title, image} = item;
        return (
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => {
              handlePress(item);
            }}
            key={id}>
            <Card
              imageUri={{uri: 'http://xxxx8xxx' + image}}
              title={title}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      })}
    </HorizontalGrid>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {meditation: state.meditation.data};
};

const mapDIspatchToProps = {
  fetchMeditation,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDIspatchToProps)(Meditation);
```

**Screenshot of Logs:**

[image: Repeated API Calls]

**EDIT:**

I was using `react native router flux` which seems not to work very well with redux. It seems to unmount the whole screen on ajax requests, which ends up causing repeated API calls.

Comment: The effect that dispatches the action that makes the request in Meditation should only be run on mount, are you re mounting the component, do you use [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) or are there other components that dispatch the same action?

Comment: have you tried passing the variable on which the useEffect should be invoked to the usEffect? in the square brackets i mean

Comment: @HMR No other components are dispatching same action, and I am not using strict mode. About re mounting, I am not doing it explicitly. As far as I am concerned,  it's like this: dispatch an action on effect, then the component renders with the received data, but rerendering causes useffect to run again. Tried using boolean flags for dependencies but that's not working as well.

Comment: @SarthakDwivedi `but rerendering causes useffect to run again` with the code you posted that can only happen when component is unmounted even when you add the missing dependency of `fetchMeditation`. Maybe you posted the wrong code in your question? Look at how `Meditation` is rendered, is it rendered conditionally based on a loading flag, that would cause re mounting?

Comment: @HMR There isn't any conditional loading and also API call is sent only once therefore empty array so no dependency. About component getting unmounted that's very much possible but I not sure about it, I am using `react-native-router-flux` package for navigation. Could that cause remounting ??

Comment: @SarthakDwivedi You can log whenever the component mounts: `useEffect(()=>console.log('component mounted'),[])` It should log as often as `fetching meditations`

Comment: @HMR Yes! It's logging as many times as `fetching meditations`, So do I take it as the component is getting remounted on each API call??

Comment: @HMR I think I found something, seems like the issue is with the package I am using for navigation. https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3363

Comment: @SarthakDwivedi Did you check how Meditation is rendered? Is the parent re rendered as well and what about the parent of its parent? Somewhere you should find the reason for the re renders.

Comment: @HMR good point but that's too much inspection after 3 days of roadblock. Removing the routing package works fine, I will switch to` react-navigation`, doesn't has a friendly API but will be a more stable solution in the long run. Thanks for helping me figure out the issue.